# Populating Select With Options From A Json Array Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

Pardon me for asking something that has been answered before. I have done my research, tried several examples and have decided to stick to this one:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

I have a json response that is in the form of an array:

```
[{"Key":"100","Value":"Allium"},{"Key":"101","Value":"Banksia"}]
```

the query-mobile front-end is as follows:

```
<select name="flower" id="flower-name"> <option value="">-Select Flower Name-</option></select>
```

Following the above example, I have two versions of the jQuery I am trying to write to populate the select options. The first produces no errors but does not populate the select with options:

```
$(function(){
$('#page-id select #flower-name').change(function(){
    var options = $('#page-id select #flower-name option');
    var url = "http://flower-server.com:80" ;
    $.getJSON(url,{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(data,options){
        options.remove();
        for (var i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
            options += '<option value="' + data[i]["Key"] + '">' + data[i]["Value"] + '</option>';
        }
        this.html(options);
    });
});
});
```

The second produces this error:

```
elem.nodeName is undefined file: /jquery.js Line 2317
```

and this is the code:

```
function flowerSelectRequest(url, selectObjId, options) {

var result = ""


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    id: $(this).val(),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){

        selectObjId.change(function() {
            options.remove();
            for (var i=0 ; i<data.length; i++){
                options += '<option value="' + data[i]["Key"] + '">' + data[i]["Value"] + '</option>';
            }
            selectObjId.html(options);
        });


    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        //error handling
    },
    complete: function(){
        // 
}
});
return result;
}

$('#page-id').live("pagecreate", function() {
var selectObjId = $('#page-id select #flower-name');
var options = $('#page-id select #flower-name option');
var url = "http://fower-server.com:80" ;
flowerSelectRequest(url, selectObjId,options);

});
```

Comment: The error you report is in jQuery, which isn't helpfull. You'll need to say which line in your code triggered the error. Use a debugger and check the call stack.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was adding the options to select.options not to select. So it should be selectObjId.append("<option value="' + data[i]["Key"] + '">' + data[i]["Value"] + '</option>");